# Unknown column error for which column I have

Tags: sql, web-applications, firebird, sqldatasource

I know this is not a good writing query :) but it does what I want when I execute it on FlameRobin. But when I try to use same query on a web app for a SqlDataSource.SelectCommand I  get unknown column error for A.SERSTATUS which I have in SERVICESCURRENT table.

```
 SELECT  A.*,
    (SELECT NAME FROM USERCODES B WHERE A.USERNAME1 = B.CODE) AS USERNAME_1, 
    (SELECT NAME FROM USERCODES B WHERE A.USERNAME2 = B.CODE) AS USERNAME_2, 
    (SELECT NAME FROM USERCODES B WHERE A.USERNAME3 = B.CODE) AS USERNAME_3,
    (SELECT NAME FROM USERCODES B WHERE A.USERNAME4 = B.CODE) AS USERNAME_4
 FROM   SERVICESCURRENT A 
    WHERE (
      (  A.SERDATE  BETWEEN '17.3.2014' AND '31.3.2014' 
         AND A.SERSTATUS != 'T' and  A.SERSTATUS != 'K' AND A.SERSTATUS != 'Y'
      ) 
      or (A.SERSTATUS  IN('AA','YY','BB' )  )
    ) ORDER BY A.SERDATE DESC 


SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
A.SERSTATUS
At line 1, column 393
```

I dont know what I do, And I cant see any reason. Any idea?? Thanks..

Comment: The logical assumption is that the table `SERVICESCURRENT` does not have a column names `SERSTATUS`.  Can you edit your query and include the definition of `SERVICESCURRENT`?

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean, sory for my english :/ definition of SERVICESCUUERNT ? but if you mean are you sure you have the field, YES I am sure I have the field. I use it many times and It is still working on other pages.

Comment: I understand it :) but I think table definition is not needed, Its too big for adding here, and again on flamerobin I get what I want. the query works, only when I put this query to sqlddatasource.selectcommand I get this error

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same database? It isn't as if Firebird suddenly forgets about the existence of a column if you use a different client.